# jquery event are not triggered automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 radio buttons that will do something when either is checked. And here is a JQuery that is tied to them:

```
$('input[name=24hours]:radio').on('change', function() {
    if($('#hours24y').is(':checked')) 
    { $('table').hide(); }
    else if ($('#hours24n').is(':checked')) 
    { $('table').show(); }
```

Also in the form I have a reset button. I tried to trigger the event above when the reset button is clicked like so:

```
$('[type=reset]').on('click', function(){
    $('input[name=24hours]:radio').triggerHandler('change');
});
```

The problem is, when the reset button is click for the first time, it only change the radio button to its initial state. The trigger jquery will only happen when the reset button is clicked again.
So, how can I make the trigger jquery automatically run on first click of reset button?

EDIT: Here's the example of action. When I check on the radio button #hours24n, a table will be shown. and if I check on the radio button #hours24y, the same table will be hidden.

let's say initially, the table is shown with #hours24n is checked. Then, I check on #hours24y thus the table will be hidden. Now, what I expect after clicking the reset button is, #hours24n will be checked and at the same time, the table will be shown again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you want. Can you try to explain a bit better? Also, you can just move the code from the change handler into the click handler without using the trigger.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1byo9nmz/1/ - can u explain what you are looking for

Comment: _"The problem is, when the reset button is click for the first time, it only change the radio button to its initial state. The trigger jquery will only happen when the reset button is clicked again. So, how can I make the trigger jquery automatically run on first click of reset button?"_ ? What is expected result ?

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
  $('input').on('change', function() {
        if ($('.radio[name=24hours]').is(':checked')) {
        { 
$('.table').fadeTo(500, 1);
this.checked = false;}

        if($('#hours24n').is(':checked'))
        { 
$('.table').fadeOut(500, 0);
this.checked = false; }
        }
    });
```

Try that, then create your table with the class 'table', saves the hassle if you need to apply more tables without using this method. Format your cells within;

```
<table class="table" style="opacity: 0"></table>
```

Comment: Try the above buddy. I'm off to bed, if you're still struggling in the morning give me a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding closing bracket, parentesis to `change` handler `})` , utilizing selector `'input[name=24hours][id=hours24n]:radio'` ,  setting `.prop("checked", true)` before calling `.triggerHandler('change')` at `click` event , calling `.click()` event to set `#hours24n` intially `checked`

```js
$(function() {
   $('input[name=24hours]:radio').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#hours24y').is(':checked')) {
      $('table').hide();
    } else if ($('#hours24n').is(':checked')) {
      $('table').show();
    }
  })

  $('[type=reset]').on('click', function() {
    $('input[name=24hours][id=hours24n]:radio')
    .prop("checked", true).triggerHandler('change');
  }).click();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="radio" name="24hours" id="hours24y" />
<input type="radio" name="24hours" id="hours24n" />
<input type="reset" />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        checked
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what if initially the #hours24y is checked instead?

Comment: _"what if initially the #hours24y is checked instead?"_ ? Not certain ? not appear described at Question ?  _"let's say initially, the table is shown with #hours24n is checked. Then, I check on #hours24y thus the table will be hidden. Now, what I expect after clicking the reset button is, #hours24n will be checked and at the same time, the table will be shown again."_ What is expected result if ` #hours24y` is checked first ? At `js` , should be set to `display:none` by calling `.show()` at `change` event ?

Comment: In the question, that was an example my friend. as seen in your code, when the reset button is clicked, the #hours24n always the one that will be checked. Also, why do you have extra ".click()". I'm still learning.

Comment: @BaimAT `.click()` http://api.jquery.com/click/ triggers `click` event , calling handler anonymous function `function() {
    $('input[name=24hours][id=hours24n]:radio')
    .prop("checked", true).triggerHandler('change');
  }` , which should call `function() {
    if ($('#hours24y').is(':checked')) {
      $('table').hide();
    } else if ($('#hours24n').is(':checked')) {
      $('table').show();
    }
  }` to set `table` `display:table` by calling `.show()`  for requirement _"let's say initially, the table is shown with #hours24n is checked. "_